# Bone Indices from GLB Files

Tags: java, 3d, model-loader

ChatGPT and I wrote a GlbImporter for a simple 3d engine written in Java. I can load any Glb model and extract and apply its diffuse textures. Extracting the bone animations is a different problem altogether. I'm pretty sure that the entire logic is written, except that I can't seem to read the bone indices for each vertex correctly. The following was written by ChatGPT, and it's only loading indices 1 or 1027. If anyone is willing to help, I could provide you with the entirety of the code.

```
private int[] extractBIArray(GlbData glbData, int meshIndex) {//Nine?
    GlbAccessor currentAccessor = glbData.boneIndicesAccessors.get(meshIndex);
    if (currentAccessor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    
    GlbBufferView bufferView = glbData.getBufferView(currentAccessor.getBufferView());
    int[] intArray = new int[currentAccessor.getCount() * 4]; // Four ints per component
    int byteOffset = bufferView.getByteOffset() + currentAccessor.getByteOffset();
    int bytesPerComponent = 4; // Each int is 4 bytes

    byte[] binaryData = glbData.getBinaryData();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(binaryData);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < currentAccessor.getCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            int intValue = buffer.getInt(byteOffset + (i * 4 + j) * bytesPerComponent);
            intArray[i * 4 + j] = intValue;
        }
    }
    
    return intArray;
}
```